# How can I move a field from a the one table to the many table in SQL?

Tags: sql, relational-database, sql-update, database-migration

How can I move a field from a the one table to the many table in a one-to-many relationship?

In our system we have a field that stores the address for an entire order (one 'Order' has many 'OrderLineItems').  We now need to allow each 'OrderLineItem' in an order to store an address.  For all orders up to this point everything was under one address so my idea was to simply set the address of each OrderLineItem to the address of its order.

- We are using MySQL 5.5.17
- Address is not a Foreign Key

Comment: what is the problem with simply removing the field from one table and adding it to the other?

Comment: I need to move the content at the same time.

Comment: ok, so you create a new field, write and run a script that moves the content, change your code to use the new field, and eventually delete the old field.  This is a pretty straight forward approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much detail in the question. What which sql server are you using? 
Is the address column a foreign key? What data type is it?

Do this in SQL Server for each address column, replacing `address_col_name` with the actual column name and specifying any constraints. Execute statements one at a time:

```
alter table OrderLineItem 
add address_col_name address_col_type; 
GO

update OrderLineItem set address_col_name = o.address_col_name 
from OrderLineItem as oli 
join Order as o on oli.OrderID = o.OrderID; 
GO

alter table Order 
drop column address_col_name; 
GO
```

There may be many other considerations but that is the basic code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not stated your RDBMS, I will assume SQL Server and you can tweak it to your RDBMS flavor:

```
alter table OrderLineItems Add Address varchar(100);

update i
set i.Address = o.Address
from OrderLineItems i
inner join Order o on o.OrderID = i.OrderID;

alter table Order Drop Column Address;
```